# new system with pcie errors need help debugging

Tags: drivers, kernel, amd-processor, pcie

I am getting some errors and was hoping some one could help debug.  What does it mean first and second what is my path to look into further debugging steps and a complete solution if possible.

Running Aorus Gaming 7 mother board with a 1950x Threadripper CPU and Nvidia 1070 with latest drivers.

Here is a link to the paste

```
system log
-------------------------
8/23/17 9:30 PM -x399   kernel  [19510.161819] dpc 0000:00:01.1:pcie010: DPC containment event, status:0x1f00 source:0x0000
8/23/17 9:30 PM -x399   kernel  [19510.161833] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: AER: Corrected error received: id=0000
8/23/17 9:30 PM -x399   kernel  [19510.161837] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=0009(Receiver ID)
8/23/17 9:30 PM -x399   kernel  [19510.161840] pcieport 0000:00:01.1:   device [1022:1453] error status/mask=00000040/00006000
8/23/17 9:30 PM -x399   kernel  [19510.161842] pcieport 0000:00:01.1:    [ 6] Bad TLP               
8/23/17 9:31 PM -x399   kernel  [19539.323943] dpc 0000:00:01.1:pcie010: DPC containment event, status:0x1f00 source:0x0000
8/23/17 9:31 PM -x399   kernel  [19539.323957] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: AER: Corrected error received: id=0000
8/23/17 9:31 PM -x399   kernel  [19539.323961] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=0009(Receiver ID)
8/23/17 9:31 PM -x399   kernel  [19539.323964] pcieport 0000:00:01.1:   device [1022:1453] error status/mask=00000040/00006000
8/23/17 9:31 PM -x399   kernel  [19539.323967] pcieport 0000:00:01.1:    [ 6] Bad TLP               
8/23/17 9:42 PM -x399   kernel  [20194.657679] dpc 0000:00:01.1:pcie010: DPC containment event, status:0x1f00 source:0x0000
8/23/17 9:42 PM -x399   kernel  [20194.657692] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: AER: Corrected error received: id=0000
8/23/17 9:42 PM -x399   kernel  [20194.657696] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=0009(Receiver ID)
8/23/17 9:42 PM -x399   kernel  [20194.657699] pcieport 0000:00:01.1:   device [1022:1453] error status/mask=00000040/00006000
8/23/17 9:42 PM -x399   kernel  [20194.657702] pcieport 0000:00:01.1:    [ 6] Bad TLP

lspci output
-------------------------
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1450
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1451
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1452
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1453
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1453
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1452
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1452
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1452
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1452
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1454
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1452
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1454
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 59)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1460
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1461
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1462
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1463
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1464
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1465
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1466
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1467
00:19.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1460
00:19.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1461
00:19.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1462
00:19.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1463
00:19.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1464
00:19.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1465
00:19.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1466
00:19.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1467
01:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ba (rev 02)
01:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43b6 (rev 02)
01:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43b1 (rev 02)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43b4 (rev 02)
02:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43b4 (rev 02)
02:03.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43b4 (rev 02)
02:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43b4 (rev 02)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1343
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device e0b1 (rev 10)
07:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a804
08:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 145a
08:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1456
08:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 145c
09:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1455
09:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
09:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1457
40:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1450
40:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1451
40:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1452
40:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1452
40:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1452
40:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1453
40:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1452
40:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1452
40:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1454
40:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1452
40:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1454
41:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b81 (rev a1)
41:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f0 (rev a1)
42:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 145a
42:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1456
42:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 145c
43:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1455
43:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
```

Comment: @muru do you think that simply amd-processor isn't specific enough as just amd-processor is not the same comparing 8320 for example with ryzen 7 1700 and then even further threadripper is an entirely different socket as well.

Comment: But why should it be so specific? Tags are meant to be broad; people use tags to follow/hide general topics of interest. How does it benefit the question to be tagged, say "tr4"? (?!)

Comment: I follow c++ for broad c++ questions, but I also follow sub-categories within the same category of c++ such as Qt, threads, or whatever.. I may want to watch for Threadripper(TR4) topics, but not ALL AMD processor topics since they are entirely different and I can't help people with those topics.

Comment: Are they entirely different, though? Are the tools associated with the various AMD processor families so different? Do completely different sets of people write the kernel code for these? Sure, maybe you can't help. But is that true of people who can help? How does fragmenting the tag space help them?

Comment: I can't speak to those topics as I don't really know for sure, but what I do know is that this particular situation ONLY effects x399 with a TR4 socket.  I haven't seen any instance of this on 8320 cpus or even the Ryzen 3/5/7 cpus.  My previous system was 8320 and talked with people on Ryzen 7 1700x and they don't have this issue.  I don't know if it fragments anything by being slightly more specific especially since it is its own socket and everything.

Comment: that makes even less sense! Why make a tag for a problem that's so specific? If the same problem occurs on the same device on another question, then it's obviously a dupe. What's the point in creating a tag for a question and its dupes?

Comment: Since you mentioned C++, I think this like creating a tag named boost-regex-1-43 because a bug happened to be in boost 1.43's regex libraries. That plainly does not make sense.

Comment: Seems like a mistake not to have hardware specific tags for troubleshooting.  I guess that is just my view point.

Comment: After finding the solution it appears you are correct.  Even having the amd-processors tag in this instance is not needed.  Could just use new motherboards or cpu tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** : I upgraded by BIOs to version F12 and now the problem is gone without the GRUB modifications.

It seems that this problem happens on many motherboards from x99 on Intel to x399 on AMD.

I can give at least a few details, even though I cannot fully explain what happens.

I originally thought TLP was some power issue, but after a little research I discovered it actually stands for transaction layer packets (TLPs).

The hardware usually detects faulty packets, and the Linux kernel reports that as messages.

The kernel option pci=nommconf disables Memory-Mapped PCI Configuration Space.
You can add this by editing grub with this command.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the variable GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and add the line below in the quotes at the end.

```
pci=nommconf
```

Mine looked like this afterwards.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nommconf"
```

This could be a hardware bug in the devices, or the controller, or something else entirely.

Although this is an actual solution that resolves the errors and not just suppresses them which without much more technical knowledge feels like a good solution.  Although personally I will look out for more motherboard BIOs updates along with kernel updates and temporarily remove the change to see if it is resolved.

Comment: Hi, I found this post googling for "usb device 1022:1453": I had this issue on kernel 5.0 every other login into gnome! Kernel 5.3 that I am now running gave good relief but now the freeze occured there, too: I will try your workaround now.

Comment: No use: it still freezes!

Comment: I had this issue a long time ago.  After I upgraded firmware and got a newer kernel I never had the issue again.  I just had the problem early on when the board first came out.  You might have to use a usb drive with the new firmware to perform the upgrade.

Comment: TY @goddard: But i am completely up to date! And i have to use vanilla 5.3 kernel, b/c i have proprietary amdgpu pro drivers.

Comment: I am on an AMD motherboard but I am using an Nvidia card.  If you are getting the same errors as me then you might need to submit a report to your motherboard manufacturer.  Mine was Gigabyte and they fixed it after a kernel patch.  Also depending on your board age, you might need to report it to the kernel devs, or at least ask them.  I mean I don't know how new your board is, but kernel version 5.5 is almost out.  You can try release candidate 4.

Comment: ty @goddard: I have submitted a bugfix request to asus. I cannot enter kernel.org bugzilla without login: where do I file a report to the kernel devs?

Comment: update: asus denied linux support for their motherboards! Kernel 5.4.10 seems to fix the issue!

Comment: That is great.  Yeah it is a shame they don't want to support Linux.

Comment: too early: I took out the `grub` configuration and also `pcie_aspm=off` which others report helpful for Threadripper error: and the error was still there!

Comment: contacted devs on kernel.org... let's wait and see!

Comment: I reported my issue here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206213